# C: read (text) file into array, can't see what's wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, file, file-read

first time posting here.  I have looked at a few other peoples ways to do this, and one of the ways was nearly exactly the same way that I am trying to do.  But, it doesn't work for me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

FILE *file;
char buffer[15];
char *text[12];

file = fopen("Text.txt", "r");

if(!file) {
    printf("Failed");
    return 1;
}


int count = 0;
while(fgets(buffer,sizeof buffer, file) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", buffer);
    text[count] = buffer;
    count++;
}   
printf("\n");
for (count=0;count<10;count++) {
    printf("%s\n", text[count]);
}

fclose(file);

return 0;
```

}

Now on another site (while looking for a solution or help I found this http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/316766/storing-string-in-a-array-reading-from-text-file

Where the person has done it the same way as me (apart from obviously slight differences in what they're reading etc).

My text file reads:
The 
Quick
Brown
Fox
Jumps
Over
The
Lazy
Dog (all on their own lines).

Basically I want to read the file in line by line and save each line in the next space in the array.

In the code when I use the line 
    printf("%s", buffer);
It prints out each word of each line okay to the console window.
However, when I print out the contents of the array with the for loop it simply prints out "dog, dog, dog..." for each space in the array.

Can someone help me here? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You did not tell on which system you are coding and against which standard do you code.

Answer (score 1):

The `buffer` is always the same address, so all the elements of array `text` contains the same pointer (or are uninitialized).

You should consider (assuming a POSIX system):

- initializing all your arrays by zeroing them (and also initialize all pointers to `NULL`), e.g. `memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));` (and for your line buffer, clear it also at the end of the loop).
- duplicating the read string with `strdup` i.e. code

  ```
  text[count] = strdup(buffer);
  ```

  and don't forget to `free` that when appropriate. Actually, you should check that `strdup` did not fail by returning a `NULL` pointer.
- use [getline](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getline.3.html) to read a line (don't forget to initialize the pointer, perhaps to `NULL` and to eventually `free` it).
- end your `printf` formatting string with a newline `\n` or else call `fflush`, notably before any input.
- use the error code `errno` to display a better error message. Or just call `perror` like

  ```
  file = fopen("Text.txt", "r");
  if (!file) {
    perror("fopen Text.txt failed");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ```

Take the habit to compile with all warnings and debugging information (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) and learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`), notably try running line by line your program.

<sup>You might be interested in coding for a strict (non POSIX) but plain C2011 standard. But then you have much less freedom to use many POSIX functions (like `strdup` etc...). I leave the boring exercise to code for strict C99 compliance to the reader (remember that C99 does not even know about directories and suppose nearly "flat" filesystems), because I am a Posix and Linux fan and don't care about non Posix systems (in particular I don't care and did not use Windows or Microsoft systems since 1990).</sup>

Also, try to read the code of some free software project (e.g. from [freecode](http://freecode.com/)). You'll learn a lot

Comment: -1: Why so many non-standard functions? Couldn't you use [`malloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html) and [`strcpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcpy.html) instead of `strdup()` and [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) instead of `getline()`?

Comment: `getline` is POSIX so standard. And likewise for `strdup`. People usually don't code purely ANSI C code. POSIX is a much better standard to code for.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated any memory for `text`. And you have to copy the value of `buffer` as it changes in each iteration. Something like:

```
while(fgets(buffer,sizeof buffer, file) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", buffer);
    text[count] = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    strcpy(text[count], buffer);
    count++;
}
```

Also, check the return value of malloc for allocation failure.

Comment: That is wrong, you did not ask `malloc` for the extra zero ending byte. And using `strdup` is really simpler and more relevant here.

Comment: Added one char. `strdup` is simpler but is posix function. May not be available on non *nix systems.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the code:

1. In the while loop you're storing the same pointer (`buffer`) over and over again into the array of pointers and you are overwriting the buffer contents too. You should probably advance the buffer pointer by the length of each read string.
2. In the for loop you're destroying the actual line count and potentially dereferencing uninitialized pointers. Don't do that.

Comment: I see, I have seen what the other answer above said and I think I know  now why that needs to be done!